# Computational tractability of matrix exponential

Tags: python, matrix, differential-equations, exponential

I need to solve a differential equation of the form: `dy/dt = H*y` where `H` is an `n x n` matrix and `y` is an `n` column vector.

I can recast the equation as `y = y_0 * Exp(H*t)`.

The options are to to run an ODE solver on the first equation or on the second form... and naively I would say that the matrix exponential would be more numerically intensive?

How would both methods scale, in terms of computational operations?

Comment: Consider that you can evaluate a matrix function by applying it to its eigenvalues. If `A = Einv * D * E`, then `F(A) = Einv * F(D) * E` where F(D) is just the function applied to each diagonal element individually.